# How can I setup a network connection for a hosted OS in Virtual PC, when the host OS doesnt have a network connection?

Tags: networking, virtual-pc

I just want a connection to talk between the hosted and the host OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help in VPC2007:

**Extending networking capabilities for virtual machines**

You can install and configure Microsoft Loopback Adapter to extend networking capabilities for virtual machines. You can use Microsoft Loopback Adapter to provide the following networking capabilities:

- Provide networking for virtual
  machines when the host operating
  system does not have a physical
  network connection available. To
  provide network connectivity between
  the host and virtual machines,
  install [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013) on
  the host operating system and then
  configure a network connection on
  each virtual machine and the host
  operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the network to local only within the vpc setting but that only let's the vpc's talk to each other and you mentioned the host pc itself. to get that you are going to have to go up a setting and use the NAT setting or or the loopback.

The settings are defined on KB 833134  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/83314